# retrieve images through stored procedure using linq to sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

the problem which i ma facing is that the stored procedure works fine when it is having a single result or a row but when the rows increase from more then one then it only retrieve the last record.
i am retrieving the url of the images from the database and then displaying them into the image tag of asp.net.
i have 2 image tags and 2 results from the database but i dont know how to place each url in each tag.

so far the code which i have tried is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using(Property_dbDataContext context=new Property_dbDataContext())
        {
            var strURL = context.retrieveImage().Select(s => s.image_url).FirstOrDefault();
            Image1.ImageUrl = strURL;
            Image2.ImageUrl = strURL.
        }
    }
```

if i just use Image1.ImageUrl = strURL; its shows me the last rest row of result.

how to get pictures via result from database in images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `context.retrieveImage()` returns the two records you're talking about, your `FirstOrDefault()` returns only one record, sorted according to the database.

You can instead store both result in a list and access those results by index:

```
var imageUrls = context.retrieveImage()
                       .Select(s => s.image_url)
                       .ToList();

Image1.ImageUrl = imageUrls[0];
Image2.ImageUrl = imageUrls[1];
```